# glew does not fetch glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance

Tags: opengl, glew, opengl-4

I'm trying to use **glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance** but the linker complains that __glewDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance is unresolved.

glew-1.9.0 is installed on the machine and as far as I can tell it should be linking it.

As temporary work around, I'm just fetching the function myself, which works. But it does not help me understand why glew does not appear to be working for that function.

And actually glew does not appear to be working for anything opengl 3.3+

To verify that the function should be available I use `glfwExtensionSupported("GL_ARB_base_instance")`.

To be clear, this is the GLFW function, not GLEW's extension checker.

I'm using glfw to create my window and a 4.3 core profile context

My system:
NVidia gtx 550 ti, with latest drivers
Ubuntu 12.04

To compile this I'm using CMake for the make files and in CMakeLists.txt:
`target_link_libraries(app GL GLU GLEW glfw)`

Comment: What compiler are you using and can you edit your question to include the full compiler command line invocation (something like `g++ foo.cpp ...`)

Comment: Also, according to this error message, it looks like you're trying to call `glewDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance` where you want `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance`

Comment: I'm calling `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance` but the linker reports `__glewDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance`

Comment: Do other extension functions work?

Comment: All extensions for opengl 3.2 and below.

Comment: You might need to update your drivers and make sure they support OpenGL 3.3+ if all the 3.3+ extensions fail to work.

Comment: The question states that I have the latest nvidia drivers, and that I'm capable of fetching the function my self.

Comment: Did you try to see if OpenGL 3.3 was supported with something like `if (GLEW_VERSION_3_3)`?  Regardless, your drivers *should* support OpenGL 4.3 according to https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver

Comment: @pwny Yet that (old drivers) would result in a runtime error when calling those rather than a linker error anyway. Sounds much more like GLEW not supporting it at all (though 1.9.0 should of course).

Comment: @ChristianRau I agree with you.  I don't know how GLEW works internally but I'm pretty sure the OpenGL implementations don't rely on GLEW being present.  That and the fact OP gets a linker error for a GLEW function when calling a GL function makes me think there's a `#define glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance __glewDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance` or something similar somewhere in GLEW which would be weird if GLEW didn't support that function.

Comment: @pwny I have tried `if (GLEW_VERSION_3_3)` and that is the first one that fails. I've looked through glew-1.9.0 in glew.c and `GL_ARB_base_instance` is supported. I just don't why its not working.

Comment: updated question to show how I'm verifying that the requested function is available.

Comment: I'm sorry but at this point I've exhausted what I can think of.  GLEW 1.9.0 should support up to OpenGL 4.3, your drivers obviously support them if they're up to date and you can actually go and get (I assume that's what you did) a pointer to the actual function.  At this point I'd file a bug in GLEW...

Comment: @pwny Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: @tamato: Have you considered... *not* using GLEW? This isn't 2008, where the only options are GLEW or GLee, you know. There are a [number of alternatives](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library), some of which actually *work* with higher OpenGL versions.

Comment: @NicolBolas tbh I haven't really looked into them, but now I'm thinking about giving OpenGL Loader Gen a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be that when installing `glew-1.9.0`, it was being installed to `/usr/lib64` and this was only one of the two problems that were happening.

One of the problems was that `glew-1.7.0` was installed in `/usr/local/lib64`, and my app was using this version of glew.

- I found this by doing `find /usr -name libGLEW*`

And the other was that `ldconfig` did not know about `/usr/lib64`.

- This was found by doing `ldconfig -p > report.txt` and looking to see what directories `ldconfig` was looking in. Which turned out to be helpful because I thought `/usr/lib64` was a "trusted" directory, and that was not the case.

Armed with this information `glew-1.7.0` was removed, `ldconfig` was updated and now everything works as expected.